# Python: Looping check for internet

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coding a script that checks if there is any internet connection. I want it to print if there were any internet connection the last time it checked as well as if there is any currently.

```
def was_able_to_connect_to_internet():
    try:
        requests.get('https://google.com')
        return True

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        return False

was_able_to_connect_to_internet_last_time = was_able_to_connect_to_internet()

while True:
    print(was_able_to_connect_to_internet_last_time, flush=True)
    print(was_able_to_connect_to_internet(), flush=True)
    print("-----", flush=True)
    sleep(5)
```

I run the code and turn of the wifi when it has looped once and get the following output:

```
True
True
-----
True
False
-----
True
False
[Cancelled]
```

If it worked like I'd want it to the results would be the followning:

```
True
True
-----
True
False
-----
False
False
[Cancelled]
```

What changes should I make? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to update your `was_able_to_connect_to_internet_last_time` variable in the loop with the new value:

```
def was_able_to_connect_to_internet():
    try:
        requests.get('https://google.com')
        return True

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        return False

was_able_to_connect_to_internet_last_time = was_able_to_connect_to_internet()

while True:
    print(was_able_to_connect_to_internet_last_time, flush=True) # Print previous status
    was_able_to_connect_to_internet_last_time = was_able_to_connect_to_internet() # Update the "previous status variable with current status"
    print(was_able_to_connect_to_internet_last_time, flush=True) # print current status using the previously updated variable to avoid pinging google twice
    print("-----", flush=True)
    sleep(5)
```

Comment: Please fix indentation.

Comment: @norok2 indentation fixed